# How can I move the sprites to be on the same level as the other sprite in Java?

Tags: java, android-studio, sprite, game-physics

The problem is my cactus' are off the screen. I am already trying place the sprites a little bit above the bottom of the screen as you can see the photo, but how can make the cactus' on the same level

I have tried to change the screenX when initialising the cactus inside the loop and also changing y variable in the sprite class but nothing seems to work.

[image] as the dino?

**GameActivity class**

```
package android.ab.t_rex;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
   public Thread thread;
   public boolean isPlaying, gameOver = false;
   private Background background1, background2;
   private Dino dino;
   private Cactus[] cacts;
   public static float screenRatioX, screenRatioY;
   private Paint paint;
   private int screenX, screenY;
   private Random random;
   private GameActivity activity;


public GameView(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {
    super(context);

    this.screenX = screenX;
    this.screenY = screenY;

    screenRatioX = 1920f / screenX;
    screenRatioY = 1080f / screenY;

    random = new Random();

    background1 = new Background(screenX, screenY, getResources());
    background2 = new Background(screenX, screenY, getResources());

    background2.x = screenX;

    dino = new Dino(screenY, getResources());

    cacts = new Cactus[4];
    // for loop to run two times, inside bird class object and each bird is added to the array
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        Cactus cactus = new Cactus(screenX, getResources());
        cacts[i] = cactus;
    }

    paint = new Paint();

}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isPlaying) {
        update();
        draw();
        sleep();
    }
}

private void update() {
    background1.x -= 10 * screenRatioX;
    background2.x -= 10 * screenRatioX;

    if(background1.x + background1.background.getWidth() < 0) {
        background1.x = screenX;
    }

    if(background2.x + background2.background.getWidth() < 0) {
        background2.x = screenX;
    }

    if(dino.isGoingUp)
        dino.y -= 30 * screenRatioY;
    else
        dino.y += 30 * screenRatioY;

    if(dino.y < 0)
       dino.y = 0;

    if(dino.y >= (screenY / 2) + (128 * (int) screenRatioX))
        dino.y = (screenY / 2) + (128 * (int) screenRatioX);

    for(Cactus cactus : cacts){
        cactus.x -= cactus.speed;
        if(cactus.x + cactus.width < 0 ){
            int leap = (int) (30 * screenRatioX);
            cactus.speed = random.nextInt(leap);
            if(cactus.speed < (int) (10 * screenRatioX)){
                cactus.speed = (int) (10 * screenRatioX);
            }
            cactus.x = screenX;
        }

        if(Rect.intersects(dino.getCollision(), cactus.getCollision())){
           gameOver = true;
        }
    }
}


private void draw() {
    if (getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) {
        // returns current canvas that is being displayed on the screen
        Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(background1.background, background1.x, background1.y, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background2.background, background2.x, background2.y, paint);

        // for the dino, position of the dino
        canvas.drawBitmap(dino.getDino(), dino.x, dino.y, paint);

        for (Cactus cactus: cacts) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(cactus.cactus1, cactus.x, cactus.y, paint);
        }

        if (gameOver) {
            isPlaying = false;
            canvas.drawBitmap(dino.getDead(), dino.x, dino.y, paint);
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            return;
            }
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
}

private void sleep() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(17);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void resume () {
    isPlaying = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void pause () {
    try {
        isPlaying = false;
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (event.getX() < screenX / 2) {
                dino.isGoingUp = true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            dino.isGoingUp = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

**This is my sprite class**

```
   package android.ab.t_rex;

   import android.content.res.Resources;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.graphics.Rect;

   import static android.ab.t_rex.GameView.screenRatioX;
   import static android.ab.t_rex.GameView.screenRatioY;

   public class Cactus {

   public int speed = 20;
   int x, y, width, height;
   Bitmap cactus1;

   Cactus(int screenY, Resources res) {
    cactus1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.cactus1);

    width = cactus1.getWidth();
    height = cactus1.getHeight();

    width = (int) (width * screenRatioX);
    height = (int) (height * screenRatioY);

    y = (screenY / 2) + (10 * (int) screenRatioX);
    x = 64 * (int) screenRatioX;

    cactus1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cactus1, width, height, false);
   }

  Rect getCollision(){
    return new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
  }
```

}

Comment: Sorry didnt post all the code!

Comment: And I can't edit my question :(